# How to run onclick function inside document.write of win.open?

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid, window.open, document.write

While working on a widget, I want to run the  onclick function on the button written by document.write(). I need essentially to use both document.open and document.write
After hours of working, I am unable to get it work.

Neither the function runs nor I am getting the value of hidden input.

```
function updateStatus(tittle, details) {

    var win = window.open("", "win", "width=auto,height=auto"); // a window object
    win.document.open("text/html", "replace");

    win.document.write("<input type='hidden' value='33' id='hidden_id'><div onclick='btn_click()'>btn</div>");

}
    function btn_click(){alert('btn_click');
        var variable=document.getElementById("hidden_id");
       alert( variable);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write btn_click() function adove updateStatus and do not forget to call updateStatus.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please update your answer with a code sample showing what you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

if your sample is the complete code listing for your project, neither function will run because neither is ever being called. Furthermore, a function does not exist until it has been declared (and therefore cannot be run until after it has been declared).

To correct your problem, btn_click function must be declared on the popup that you're opening. Also, the call to updateStatus must be somewhere on the first page (not the popup), since that's the page that creates the popup. If applicable, it could be called from the body tag's onload event like this.

```
<body onload="updateStatus('mytitle','my details');">
    ...
</body>
```